# Cannot deserialize a java.lang.Object in Jersey when receiving it from server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jaxb, jax-rs, jax-ws

I am trying to get an object from a server using rest Jersey. 
So i am sending a GenericResponse object containing GenericHeader and GenericObject. 
It's all good until i'm trying to get the object from Response.
So i can get the message from GenericHeader, but not GenericObject.
and i'm getting a **java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to Object.** no matter what i use json/xml

UPDATE : I'm only getting the object back with xml, and same exception for json.
Stack-Trace : https://pastebin.com/8wqFwjeW

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class GenericResponse {

    private GenericHeader genericHeader;
    private GenericObject genericObject;

    // setters, getters -> @XMLElement annotated
}



import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class GenericHeader {

    private String message;

    // setters, getters -> @XMLElement annotated
}


import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class GenericObject {

    private Object object;

    // setters, getters -> @XMLElement annotated


}
```

Client call :

```
GenericResponse genericResponse = client.target("URL")          
    .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    .post(Entity.xml(objectSent), GenericResponse.class);           
if(genericResponse.getGenericHeader().isSuccess()) {    
    log.info("Message : " + genericResponse.getGenericHeader().getMessage());
    User userResp = (User) genericResponse.getGenericObject().getObject();
}
```

Comment: Post the entire stack trace verbatim.

Comment: An update: works only with xml, when i try with json it gives me this exception 
https://pastebin.com/8wqFwjeW